# opening only part of large TDMS files in python, as Labview does

Tags: python, labview

I have large (>20GB, larger than RAM) .tdms files created in Labview to open in python3.  I can use [`nptdms`](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS) with the option `memamp_dir` to leave the RAM untouched. But this writes another large file on the disk, which is sometimes a problem and it's slow.

Labview has the possibility to [read](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/tdms_file_read/) only part of the file, quite quickly. 
Is that possible in python with `nptdms` or other?

(It seems discussed [here](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/issues/39), but I cannot find an easy solution. Also, [`nptdms.tdms_segment.py`](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/blob/master/nptdms/tdms_segment.py) could be part of the solution but it's hard to understand how it works for me)

Comment: Another option is to use TestScript to have Python tell LabVIEW to do it. TestScript is here: https://www.winemantech.com/testscript-download. It's a fully bidirectional LabVIEW/Python connector.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with [iqtools](https://github.com/xaratustrah/iqtools) library. I regularly use it to jump to a certain position of very large files (tested around 5GB) using `seek` and read a portion only, not the whole file. Generally you should consider the TDMS file containing a huge string of data points with a bit of complex data format inside, **length of frames**, **number of frames** are basically numbers for your analysis convenience. "Jumping" is done using the **starting frame** argument.

```
from iqtools import *
filename ='blah.tdms'
myiq=TDMSData(filename)
myiq.read(nframes=100, lframes=1024, sframes=400)
```

Which means reading 100 frames each 1024 samples long starting from sample 400.

For very small files, there is also another `read_complete_file` function. In the library there are many other tools for spectral analysis such as 1D and 2D spectrograms, **multi taper** etc. There are some examples in the repository.

btw. [iqtools](https://github.com/xaratustrah/iqtools) library has also a GUI front end called [IQGUI](https://github.com/xaratustrah/iqgui), which, although not as versatile as the library interface, can be used to "traverse" through the time file using a visual slider.

maybe this can help.